# ['“Invalid date” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']

Tags: javascript, django, date, fullcalendar

Currently I am making fullcalendar using Django. The problem arises when I want to update the time.

add_event looks like this.

```
def add_event(request):
     title = request.GET.get("title", None)
     start = request.GET.get("start", None)
     end = request.GET.get("end", None)
     event = Events(title=str(title), start=start, end=end)
     event.save()
     data = {}
     return JsonResponse(data)
```

Add_event function seems to have no problem because when I execute it, it works properly.

```
"GET /fullcalendar/add_event?title=testtime6&start=2020-08-06T00%3A00%3A00&end=2020-08-06T00%3A00%3A00&id=365&allDay=true HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

But when I want to update the date, the error came out like this.

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“Invalid date” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
[06/Aug/2020 14:28:41] "GET /fullcalendar/update?title=testtime6&start=Invalid+date&end=Invalid+date&id=367&allDay=false HTTP/1.1" 500 17368
```

update looks like this.

```
def update(request):
    start = request.GET.get("start", None)
    end = request.GET.get("end", None)
    title = request.GET.get("title", None)
    id = request.GET.get("id", None)
    event = Events.objects.get(id=id)
    event.start = start
    event.end = end
    event.title = title
    event.save()
    data = {}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

My question is why I can add_event without no problem but suddenly when I want to update it, the date becomes invalid?

Any idea about it?

Comment: What is the datetime format of `start` and `end` in both views? Check whether those formats are different.

Comment: for add_event view, the format is [%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S] but I'm not sure about the update view. Do you know how I can check the datetime for update view? I'm assuming it's the same because why the datetime format would be different anyway? I turn off the timezone and the date that is taken and inserted into database is naive time(I think)

Comment: check the values of `start` and `end` in each view and ***identify*** the date format